# Iterate through inputs inside of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, iteration

I'am trying to iterate through all inputs which are placed on a specific div via jQuery, but there is no response. I can't see the values of inputs by using alert. What am I doing wrong ?

```
<form id="internshipStage2Form" method="POST" action="form2.php">
    <center>
        <table id="studentInformation" border="1">
            <caption style="color:#f00;">Student(Trainee) Information</caption>
            <tr>
                <td valign="middle" align="center">
                    <label id="stuEmailLabel" for="stuEmailText">E-mail Address</label>
                </td>
                <td valign="middle" align="center"><?php echo $email; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="middle" align="center">
                    <label id="stuPhoneLabel" for="stuPhoneText">Phone</label>
                </td>
                <td><input id="stuPhoneText" type="text" name="stuPhoneText"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="companyInfo">
            <table id="companyInformation" border="1">
                <caption style="color:#f00;">Company Information</caption>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="middle" align="center">
                        <label id="companyNameLabel" for="companyNameText">Company Name</label>
                    </td>
                    <td><input id="companyNameText" type="text" name="companyNameText"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="middle" align="center">
                        <label id="companyAdressLabel" for="companyAdressText">Address</label>
                    </td>
                    <td><input id="companyAdressText" type="text" name="companyAdressText"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="middle" align="center">
                        <label id="companyPhoneLabel" for="companyPhoneText">Phone</label>
                    </td>
                    <td><input id="companyPhoneText" type="text" name="companyPhoneText"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="middle" align="center">
                        <label id="" for="">Did the any students work as trainees in the company in the previous years?</label>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="middle" align="center">
                        Yes<input id="g1Positive" type="radio" name="g1" value="YES"/>
                        No<input id="g1Negative" type="radio" name="g1" value="NO"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <h4 style="color:#f00;">
            I agree the terms.
        </h4>
        <input id="stuDecCheckBox" type="checkbox" name="stuDecCheckBox" /></br>
        <input id="sendButton" type="submit" name="sendButton2" value="SEND FOR APPROVEMENT"/>
    </center>
</form>
```

JS

```
$('#companyInfo').children('input').each(function () {
    alert(this.value);
});
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the [`<center>` element is (long) deprecated and obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center), in HTML 4, no less.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your inputs are not children of `#companyInfo`. Just do this:

```
$('#companyInfo input').each(function () {
    alert(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `find` method, which looks for nested elements at any level:

```
$('#companyInfo').find('input').each(function () {
    alert(this.value);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/geLq4/

Answer (score 4):

The `input`s are not immediate descendants of `#companyInfo`. [Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/5UB99/1/) instead:

```
$('#companyInfo input').each(function () {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/children/):

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree

Classes make a great way to implement multi-element operations quickly.

```
Yes<input class="radioInput" id="g1Positive" type="radio" name="g1" value="YES"/>
No<input class="radioInput" id="g1Negative" type="radio" name="g1" value="NO"/>
```

Then use .each to iterate by class:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '#sendButton', function() {
        $(' .radioInput ').each(function() {
            alert(this.value);
        });
    });
});
```

And a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5qZL8/) for you.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
 var baseInfosInputs = [];
 $("#baseInfos :input, #baseInfos :selected").each(function() {
     baseInfosInputs += this.value;
 });
```

If you want push them into an array or an object use this:

```
baseInfosInputs.push(this.value);
```

Comment: This is rather unnecessary as jQuery already accumulates elements matching a selector in a list.