# Dynamically add/remove forms groups and give unique id and names for each inputs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a complex CMS kind of thing. Basically what I want is to create more form inputs on click of a button and even remove them by another button. The script is already working, but each input has the same name. I want to write a php script to submit the data in a database. So i want all of them to have unique name and id.

I have the following JS/jQuery/HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //group add limit
  var maxGroup = 7;
  //add more fields group
  $(".addMore").click(function() {
    if ($('body').find('.fieldGroup').length < maxGroup) {
      var fieldHTML = '<div class="row fieldGroup">' + $(".fieldGroupCopy").html() + '</div>';
      $('body').find('.fieldGroup:last').after(fieldHTML);
    } else {
      alert('Maximum ' + maxGroup + ' groups are allowed.');
    }
  });

  //remove fields group
  $("body").on("click", ".remove", function() {
    $(this).parents(".fieldGroup").remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section>
  <div class="row fieldGroup">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="productId">ID :</label>
        <input type="text" name="productId[]" class="form-control" id="productId[]"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="productName">Name :</label>
        <input type="text" name="productId[]" class="form-control" id="productName[]">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="price">Price :</label>
        <input type="number" name="price[]" id="price[]" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="commission">Commission :</label>
        <input type="number" name="commission[]" id="commission[]" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success addMore"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add</a>
  </div>

  <div class="row fieldGroupCopy" style="display: none;">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="productId">ID :</label>
        <input type="text" name="productId[]" class="form-control" id="productId[]"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="productName">Name :</label>
        <input type="text" name="productId[]" class="form-control" id="productName[]">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="price">Price :</label>
        <input type="number" name="price[]" id="price[]" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="commission">Commission :</label>
        <input type="number" name="commission[]" id="commission[]" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span> Remove</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Everything works as desired except the name and id arrays dont work.
I want the name be like productId1, productId2, productId3 and so on.
Similarly, I want the name be like price1, price2 etc.
Same is the case for commission and name.

I want the output to have unique id and names so that I can write php script easily to submit the form.

When I click on the add button, a new form group is created but it has the same id and name as the previous one. I want an array in place of those square brackets[]

Answer (score 0):

Need to follow two steps:
1) You just have to maintain counter in input type hidden and increment it on each click. 
and give id to particular Div.

```
var cnt=0;  

$(".addMore").click(function() {
    if ($('body').find('.fieldGroup').length < maxGroup) {
      var fieldHTML = '<div class="row fieldGroup" id="dynamicfrom+ cnt>' + $(".fieldGroupCopy").html() + '</div>';
      $('body').find('.fieldGroup:last').after(fieldHTML);
     cnt++;
    } else {
      alert('Maximum ' + maxGroup + ' groups are allowed.');
    }
  });
```

2) after adding new form group , loop throu all input of form and change it's name by counter id.

```
$('#divformgroup(Counter) input').each(function () {
  //Here change name of input.
$('input').attr('name', 'yourNewname');
});
```

you can follow this links:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24619440/iterate-through-inputs-inside-of-a-div)
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34622125/how-do-i-change-the-input-name-in-jquery)

Comment: Can you please elaborate through the second code part.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/spbf15mk/3/ you can follow this link, but need to change so logic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it is not working as desired. I want the newly added inputs to have attributes like name="product1" name="product2" ... and so on. Similiar is the case for the id attribute. I want the new id to be id="someid1" id="someid2" .. etc.